# Removing unnecessary character from a string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

```
AB753217|Influenza A virus (A/African Stonechat/Vietnam/8/2009(H9N2)) |H9N2 |4 (HA)|2009-11-12
```

I want to remove some characters from the faster header such that the output looks like this  using r

```
AB753217|A/African Stonechat/Vietnam/8/2009|H9N2 |HA|2009-11-12
```

I have tried using `gsub()` but it seems my code is wrong:

```
df_1$isolate_name <- gsub("Influenza A virus \\(","", df_1$isolate_name) 
df_1$isolate_name <- gsub("\\)_segment.*gene", "", df_1$isolate_name)
```

Comment: `gsub("(?<=[|])[^|()]+\\(([^()]+)[^|]*","\\1", txt, perl =TRUE)`

Comment: The first gsub should work, only this pattern `\\)_segment.*gene` is not present in the string right? Is there any logic to it, or are you specifically looking to match those strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove everything between `|` and `(` what is not a `(` or `|`: `\\|[^(|]+\\(`, or everything between `(` or `)` and `|` what is not a `|`: `[()][^|]*\\|` and reinsert the `|`.

```
s <- "AB753217|Influenza A virus (A/African Stonechat/Vietnam/8/2009(H9N2)) |H9N2 |4 (HA)|2009-11-12"

gsub("\\|[^(|]+\\(", "|", s) |> gsub("[()][^|]*\\|", "|", x=_) #In two separate steps

gsub("(?<=\\|)[^(|]+\\(|[()][^|]*(?=\\|)", "", s, perl=TRUE) #In one step using non consuming look ahead / behind and or |

#[1] "AB753217|A/African Stonechat/Vietnam/8/2009|H9N2 |HA|2009-11-12"
```